# jQuery validation is not applying jQuery HTML

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I am using jQuery validation plugin. It's working well but it's not applying html which is added by jquery.

```
$("#search_form").validate({
        rules: {
            "origin[]": "required",
            "destination[]": "required",
            "departure[]": "required",
            return_date: "required",
            "origin[]": {
                required: true
            },
            "destination[]": {
                required: true
            },
            "departure[]": {
                required: true
            },
            return_date : {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            "origin[]": "required",
            "destination[]": "required",
            "departure[]": "required",
            return_date: "required"
        },
        errorElement: "em",
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.addClass("help-block");
            element.parents(".input-group").addClass("has-feedback");
            if (!element.next("span")[ 0 ]) {
                $("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback'></span>").insertAfter(element);
            }
        },
        success: function (label, element) {
            if (!$(element).next("span")[ 0 ]) {
                $("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback'></span>").insertAfter($(element));
            }
        },
        highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).parents(".input-group").addClass("has-error").removeClass("has-success");
            $(element).next("span").addClass("glyphicon-remove").removeClass("glyphicon-ok");
        },
        unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).parents(".input-group").addClass("has-success").removeClass("has-error");
            $(element).next("span").addClass("glyphicon-ok").removeClass("glyphicon-remove");
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });
```

when I add the input field in the form using jQuery then jQuery validation is not applying on this field. How I can apply this validation on the newly created input field using jQuery.